# Receiving and sending cookies with Go client?

Tags: cookies, web, go, http-authentication

I want my Go application to authenticate with a website and then use the received cookie to access secure locations. The following curl examples illustrates exactly what I'm trying to do:

*Authenticate with website via `x-www-form-urlencoded` and save cookie. Data is urlencoded automatically:*

```
curl 'https://www.example.com/login' \
    --cookie-jar cookies.txt \
    --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
    --data 'user=USER NAME&pass=PASS'
```

*Now authentication cookie is saved in `cookies.txt` and I just send that to access a page that requires login:*

```
curl 'https://www.example.com/profile' \
    --cookie cookies.txt
```

I don't want to store the cookie on disk in my application, only in memory so I can use it when required.

Does anyone have an example of how this can be achieved in Go?

Comment: Yes, use an [http.CookieJar](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#CookieJar). See [What is the difference between cookie and cookiejar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31270461/what-is-the-difference-between-cookie-and-cookiejar/31270794#31270794)

Comment: Thanks. Nice and clear explanation. I return a pointer to `cookiejar.Jar` from my authentication function and use this with `http.Client` in another function.

Answer (score 0):

For golang you can [Add a cookie](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.AddCookie) to a request you can also get cookies using [this](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Response.Cookies) function after making a web request.

Answer (score 0):

you will find that Golang's approach is much similar to the one in Java.
make sure you are inside your login handler.
you only set the cookie using the `SetCoookie` function

```
myCookie := http.Cookie{
    Name: "cookie Name",
    Value: "cookieValue",
  }

  http.SetCookie(w, &myCookie)
```

it is recommended for security reasons to add the httpOnly flag to your cookie.

```
httpOnly: true
```

this flag true has nothing to do with HTTPS/HTTP.
it only means no scripts allowed, HTTP requests only, to prevent Cross-site scripting (XSS) attacks.
you store the cookie from the client-side, then when required you call the cookie and you verify if it the right cookie and the right client u send it to.
this approach can be done using:

```
cookie, err := r.Cookie("appointment")
checkErr(err)
```

now u decrypt the cookie. verify it. do whatever the hell u want with it.
then return your response to the client if it is the right client or not.
hope this kinda helps