# Parsing set-cookie header in go

Tags: parsing, go, cookies

I want to parse cookies returned by a POST request into a cookie jar but I can't find any documentation on this. Are there some good packages or so out there? Or how do I do it?

Edit: it's not a duplicate. I am asking about parsing cookies returned by set-cookie, not sending cookies just by sending.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Go HTTP Post and use Cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12756782/go-http-post-and-use-cookies)

Comment: net/http.Request.Cookies does all you need, so what is the question?

Comment: Also: Parsing a Set-Cookie HTTP header in itself does not help much in adding to a cookie jar.

Answer (score 2):

It's not expected that you construct a cookie jar manually. Instead pass an `http.CookieJar` interface to an `http.Client` when making the request and the cookies will be automatically handled for you.

More information in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31270461/what-is-the-difference-between-cookie-and-cookiejar)

Essentially you would use the http client, and the cookiejar implementation here:
https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/cookiejar/

To do something like:

```
// All users of cookiejar should import "golang.org/x/net/publicsuffix"
jar, err := cookiejar.New(&cookiejar.Options{PublicSuffixList: publicsuffix.List})
if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
}

client := &http.Client{
        Jar: jar,
}
```

Example taken from here:
https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/cookiejar/#example_New

Comment: I did that and cookie jar returns no cookies after the request.

Comment: @gevageyo If you have some code that doesn't work, you'd better show us in the question. Aim for a [mcve].

Comment: Is there some way to debug a jar to see all cookies inside?

Comment: I think it's the problem with cookiejar implementation. See this:
http://jcla1.com/blog/improving-go-cookie-handling

Answer (score 0):

Needs to be HTTP/S call to work with cookieJar, try setting the URL.Scheme to HTTP. Should work